# What is the critical region for this Poisson test?

Tags: statistical-inference

Could someone help start part c of this question, is the Neyman-Person Lemma useful in c and d?

*In order to satisfy quality control, the mean number of flaws in aluminum sheets must be less than or equal to 0.6 flaws per meter length. A length of 7m is inspected. Assuming the number of flaws follows a Poisson distribution:
(a) State the distribution of the number of flaws (X) in the length sampled-assuming an average of 0.6 flaws per meter.
(b) State the hypothesis for the test.
(c) Find the critical region for the test at the 5% significance level
(d) Find the probability of:

(i)A type I error
(ii) A type II error, given the mean is in fact 0.72 flaws per meter*